# FirebaseUI NoSuchMethodException:

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

I just share the relevant code:

MainActivity:

```
 RecyclerView recyclerView;

        DatabaseReference databaseReference;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_todo);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);


        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);



        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);





        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Grupo,GruposAdapter.ViewHolder> adapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Grupo, GruposAdapter.ViewHolder>(
                    Grupo.class,
                        R.layout.item,
                        GruposAdapter.ViewHolder.class,
                        databaseReference.child("Grupos")


        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(GruposAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, Grupo model, int position) {
                    viewHolder.id.setText(String.valueOf(model.getId()));
                    viewHolder.grupo.setText(model.getGroupname());
            }
        };



        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

The error:

```
04-19 14:50:52.886 22120-22120/datos.agregar.firebase.ejemplo.com.ejemploagregardatoscffirebase E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                                  Process: datos.agregar.firebase.ejemplo.com.ejemploagregardatoscffirebase, PID: 22120
                                                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.view.View]
```

Why `NoSuchMethodException` ? ideas?

FIXED WITH:

```
  public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView id,grupo;
        public CardView cardview;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);

            id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idgrupo);
            grupo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.grupo);
            cardview = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your `GruposAdapter.ViewHolder` is lacking the required constructor. See https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/46#issuecomment-167373575. From there:

> There are two likely causes for this:
>
> - make sure that your TaskViewHolder class is public
>     *if your TaskViewHolder is an inner class of e.g. your activity, make sure it's static
>
> So likely
>
> ```
> public static TaskViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
> ```

Comment: Hi, you are right,  fixed with the inner class like static, but why? why i need static the class viewholder?

Comment: Because you added it as an inner class inside another class. Java adds an implicit field and constructor parameter to such classes to refer to the containing object (e.g. that's what you use when you refer to `MainActivity.this` in a click handler). Adding `static` to the class removes that field/parameter.